# How to trim all the columns after a column name is found None in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
ID    Sr. No     Col_1    None    Col_2
1      10         Abc     None    XUZ_09
2      20         Xyz     None    Abc_227
```

I want to discard every thing After `None` field i.e. After `Col_1`.
One way to do is as follows:

```
df_final = df_final.iloc[:,:-3]
```

But I want to make the `-3` dynamic. So the resultant Dataframe would be

```
ID    Sr. No     Col_1    
 1      10         Abc     
 2      20         Xyz
```

Any clue on this please?

Answer (score 3):

Or taking by the column name:

```
df = df.iloc[:, :(df.columns == 'None').argmax()]
```

Comment: this needs a small tweak
df = df.iloc[:, :(df.columns == 'None').argmax()-1]

Comment: Not really. This would drop Col_1.

Answer (score 2):

### Creating the Dataframe

```
d = {
'ID': [1,2,34],   
'Sr. No': [13,23,343],     
'Col_1': [1,23,4345],    
'None': [None, None, None], 
'Col_3': [None, None, None] 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

```
df

ID  Sr. No  Col_1   None    Col_3
0   1   13  1       None    None
1   2   23  23      None    None
2   34  343 4345    None    None
```

### Splitting the dataframe with "None" column

```
columns = df.columns.to_list()
split_index = columns.index('None')
df = df[columns[:-split_index + 1]]
```

### Result

```
df
ID  Sr. No  Col_1
0   1   13  1
1   2   23  23
2   34  343 4345
``
```

Answer (score 1):

If column name is `None` like `NoneType` or `None` like string use solution with compare it and [`Index.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.cumsum.html) with compare values before first matched values by compare `0`, last pass to [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `:` for get all rows and columns by mask:

```
d = {
'ID': [1,2,34],   
'Sr. No': [13,23,343],     
'Col_1': [1,23,4345],    
'None': [None, None, None] 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

mask = (df.columns.isna() | (df.columns == 'None')).cumsum() == 0
df1 = df.loc[:, mask]    
print (df1)
   ID  Sr. No  Col_1
0   1      13      1
1   2      23     23
2  34     343   4345
```

---

```
d = {
'ID': [1,2,34],   
'Sr. No': [13,23,343],     
'Col_1': [1,23,4345],    
None: [None, None, None] 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

mask = (df.columns.isna() | (df.columns == 'None')).cumsum() == 0
df1 = df.loc[:, mask]    
print (df1)
   ID  Sr. No  Col_1
0   1      13      1
1   2      23     23
2  34     343   4345
```

---

```
d = {
'ID': [1,2,34],   
'Sr. No': [13,23,343],     
'Col_1': [1,23,4345],    
'col_z': [None, None, None] 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

mask = (df.columns.isna() | (df.columns == 'None')).cumsum() == 0
df1 = df.loc[:, mask]    
print (df1)
   ID  Sr. No  Col_1 col_z
0   1      13      1  None
1   2      23     23  None
2  34     343   4345  None
```

EDIT:

```
d = {
'ID': [1,2,34],   
'Sr. No': [13,23,343],     
'Col_1': [1,23,4345] 
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[1,None,5])

mask = (df.index.isna() | (df.index== 'None')).cumsum() == 0

df1 = df.loc[mask]
print (df1)
   ID  Sr. No  Col_1
1   1      13      1
```

Comment: how to drop all 'subsequent' all rows, if a row is seen 'None'? Especially, how to use the `mask` for dropping the rows instead of columns.

Comment: @pythondumb - Can you test `mask = (df.index.isna() | (df.index== 'None')).cumsum() == 0` and then `df1 = df.loc[mask]`  ?

Comment: Not happening. Initial `df.shape[0]==1074`. After applying your code I am getting same.

Comment: @pythondumb - added sample test to `EDIT` and working very well, so it seems problem in data or not understand what need.

Comment: I used the following. Step 1: I found out the index number `n` where all the rows are blank. `n=df.isnull.sum(axis=1).idxmax()`. Step 2: `df =df.iloc[0:n:,]`